# Access directive element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How do I access the element my directive is attached to inside the directive class itself? I need the reference to the element to apply styles via the `Renderer` service. Using `ElementRef.nativeElement` works, but that is being [officially discouraged](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html), so I'm wondering what other options we have.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[autoGrow]',
    host: {
        '(focus)': 'onFocus()',
        '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
    }
})
export class AutoGrowDirective {
    constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}

    /*
     * This code works, but uses ElementRef.nativeElement to reference the element
     */
    onFocus() {
        this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._el.nativeElement, 'width', '200px');
    }

    onBlur() {
        this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._el.nativeElement, 'width', '120px');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `ElementRef.nativeElement...` should be avoided. Using `ElementRef` or `ElementRef.nativeElement` with methods from `Renderer` is just fine.

For predefined styles you don't need `ElementRef` though. You can just use host binding like

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[autoGrow]',
    host: {
        '(focus)': 'onFocus()',
        '(blur)': 'onBlur()',
        '[style.background-color]': '"red"',
        '[style.left.px]': '"10"',
        '[style.top.%]': 'someProp',
    }
})   
export class AutoGrowDirective {
  someProp:number = 20;

  // or like
  @HostBinding('style.color') 
  someProp:string = 'grey';
}
```

Comment: The `Renderer` methods require the `nativeElement` to get passed (since some later beta version) as parameter and this is still fine. What you should **avoid** is accessing properties or methods of `nativeElement` directly in your code.